# $λ={41/10\left(\frac{1}{2^2-1}+\frac{1}{4^2-1}+\frac{1}{6^2-1}+..+\frac{1}{40^2-1}\right)}$ then $w+w^λ$ is equal to

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation

Given that,

$$λ={41/10\left(\frac{1}{2^2-1}+\frac{1}{4^2-1}+\frac{1}{6^2-1}+..+\frac{1}{40^2-1}\right)}$$

then $w+w^λ$ is equal to ?
[$w$ is cube root of unity other than 1]
I cannot understand how to simplify λ ! Help please!

Comment: Hint: Use telescopy to calculate the series in the denominator.

Comment: What is that @PrasunBiswas! I dont know..give me a link or something so that i can learn

Comment: Do you know about telescoping series?

Comment: no i dont...please explain

Comment: By the way, are you sure that the question you posed is correct? Because I see a simpler answer if the series is multiplied, not divided!

Comment: Its multiplied!!not divided!!!

Comment: Then, you should edit it properly.

Comment: Done!!And btw you only edited it :-P!!Ok i got what you meant by telescoping series!!Thanks !! :-)

Comment: So, do you need the solution? I see that the answer comes out as $(-1)$.

Comment: No..i solved it just now...thanks to your telescope method,λ=2.

Comment: w+w^2=-1...done !!! yipee!!

Comment: Thank You..@PrasunBiswas!!No its ok...i'll write the solution!:-)

Comment: Well, I didn't see this and so wrote the answer. Hope you upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we compute the series multiplied with the scalar $\dfrac{41}{10}$.

The sum (say $S$) can be represented compactly as,

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{20}\left(\frac{1}{(2i)^2-1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{20}\left(\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{20}\left(\frac{(2i+1)-(2i-1)}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}\right)\\ \implies 2S=\sum_{i=1}^{20}\left(\frac{1}{2i-1}-\frac{1}{2i+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{41}=\frac{40}{41}\implies S=\frac{20}{41}$$

Note that the sum was evaluated in the last step using the technique of telescoping sums.

Now, $\lambda=\dfrac{41}{10}\cdot S\implies \lambda=2$

This makes the required expression to be evaluated $w+w^2$

Using the result $1+w+w^2=0$, the answer we get is $(-1)$.

$$\Bbb{Q.E.D}$$